# Why would one want to query the compositioncontainer?

Tags: .net, mef

What is a good reason for querying the composition container (other than debugging and fooling around). In a practical application scenario, why would I want to use GetExports or GetExportedValues? What would the benefit be over using an import or importmany other than not needing an additional class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three reasons that I know of:

1. **Force Majeure**

   Some 3rdparty code (over which you have no control) instantiates your classes by name via reflection. Those classes will then have to take care of their composition themselves in the constructor.
2. **Gradual refactoring**

   Suppose you already have a large existing code base, written without DI in mind. You want to gradually refactor it to use dependency injection.

   Say you pick a random class and change it to use dependency injection: now you will typically see that you will also have to change any classes which instantiates that class instead of receiving an injected dependency. And if you correct that, you also need to change the classes which instantiate *those* classes etcetera.

   To avoid a cascade where you have to immediately change the whole code base in one refactoring, it is often convenient to temporarily insert extra composition roots.
3. **Happy without DI**

   You already have a code base without inversion of control that you are happy with, you just want to add one or more extension points. Or perhaps you're already using the Service Locator pattern instead of dependency injection.

Answer (score -1):

Generally for example when you need to dynamically load ONE export only. Dynamically depending on some input, for example.

There are tons of scenarios where an Import - which is hard-coded into the receiving class - does not work.

One example is lifetime. With GetExport / GetExportedValue I can ask for a database repository AND DISPOSE IT outside of the object lifetime. This comes in handy for elements that may or may not need a repository and if they need one need to get rid of it without getting rid of the whole class ;)

Then there is a service type of scenario, which i often use. My server apps have services that are NOT INITIALIZED UNTIL STARTED - which quite obviously means that an Import can not work, which creates the whole object structure upon service creation, not service start ;) There are good reasons towards this - for example that a configuration may detemrine which services to start on a specific machine, and some of my services are kind of memory heavy (pulling a gigabyte or two or ten cached data on start), so when it is not started... it better does not even exist.

Comment: `IDisposable` objects acquired with `GetExport` are owned by the container. The container will reuse them for multiple imports (unless you specified `PartCreationPolicy.NonShared`) and will dipose them when you dispose the container. Therefore you should not dispose them yourself. A better solution for managing lifetime is to import `ExportFactory<T>`.

For postponing initialization, you can import `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: Still valid. I have the scenario where a worker thread would load drivers. It accumulatd them until it finished every 16k packets. BU it did not want all possible drivers instantiated.